# Mango plant drying out after rubbing off white small insects

Tags: fruit-trees

My plant was full of white small insects really small ones and a lot of them in big amount on a small surface of the leaves and branches.. and instead of using soap and olive oil solution i started to remove them with hand by rubbing on the plants surface, and after 3 weeks this happened..see the pic.. 
i wrapped the lower branches with wet papertowel.. i give the plant yeast containing water , i sprinkle it what else can i do?maybe bigger pot?  I live in zone 8, during winter it is inside from april [image]it is outside, it is Gomera -3 type of mango
Thx for any help. Adam

Comment: Mango plants are not easy to die (unless they are very young ). It's often to me seeing all the leaves falling down because of heavy fungus infestation and not even a single leaf left. Then, after several weeks they grow again. This is just my personal experience growing them with almost no care outside my house. They love rain BTW, it somehow clean them as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess Adam I would assume that what your seeing with your mango is a direct result of those bugs sucking the sap from the tree. Give it time and hopefully, with any luck, they won't have killed it. I would change the soil as they tend to infest it and lay their larva in it.